# Batch if first time starting

Tags: batch-file

I'm in progress of making little program...So, if you are new user, program must open new programs that asks for priviliges..

So i made something like this:

```
:reg
if exist reg.txt goto home
if not exist reg.txt goto firsttime
```

And "firsttime" its:

```
:firsttime
cls
echo Welcome! Bla bla bla
*making reg.txt so when you start app next time
it wont open firsttime anymore*
```

But program sents me to firsttime every time! Anybody that can help me? Thanks! <3

Comment: Is reg.txt in the same directory as the batch script?

Comment: Do you have a `:home` section?

Comment: Yes! I have :home selection but i dont want to share whole code..And yea, reg.txt its in same directory.

Comment: For some reason it sents me to "firsttime" :(

Comment: try `if exist "%dp0reg.txt" goto home`. Does that work?

Comment: No.. Still it bugs me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the line to read:

```
:reg
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\reg.txt" (goto :home) Else (goto :firsttime)
Goto :EOF
```

This will look for the file in the user profile folder, but you can change it to any other folder.

You need to specify the full path to the file or else it might look in the wrong spot. You can use C:\ or \\share\folder paths, but it needs to be given.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful critique, and I have updated the answer to reflect your suggestion. The reason for the Goto :EOF after the If statement is just to prevent a mistype on the batch writer to prevent the flow of execution to pass beyond that point, and that I usually use call instead of goto, so it is a personal habit of mine.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I needed to add "protection" to code so it wont fall thru. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Without more code than you've posted, it's impossible to tell.

It *could* be that your code "falls through" to `:firsttime` - without it, we can't tell.

I would code this as

```
:reg
set "regfile=c:\reg.txt"
if exist "%regfile%" goto home
:: First time through
cls
echo Blah blah blah
...
echo something>"%regfile%"
:home
```

Naturally, the precise absolute pathname and filename are entirely up to you.

You might (not specified) want to include the username in the path or filename, or you may want to store all of the data about multiple users in a single file - not specified, and needs a completely different approach...

Comment: Yea it fell thru. But i used CoveGeek's code and it worked